# xml validate allowed values in java

Tags: java, xml, validation, parsing, xsd

I have a question what is the best way to validate XML against XSD. I need to validate allowed values in XML, which can be easily done in XSD using enumeration. Problem is, that the list of allowed values is quite big and do this in XSD could be paintfull. Another thing is, that allowed values can be changed from time to time, so I would like to avoid changing XSD schema. I was thinking to filter this values by using java. E.g. to make some config files for each XML tag filled with values and when validating XML, values would be checked. If content of XML tag is not in config file, error would be raised. 
My another question is, which parser is the best to do this? XML file has arround 40 XML elements/tags, one XML file could have around 40k records. 
And my last question is, how can I change english language of errors which are default in parser? I have read some tutorials which parser to use, but your experiences would be really helpfull. Thank you

example of values:

`<order>pancake</order>`

`<order>milk</order>`

Pancake is allowed value, so no error is raised. Milk is not allowed, so the error would be raised: Milk is not allowed.

Comment: is it right that you don't want the values enumerated in xsd _or_ in java? then you  would need some kind of logic/restriction for the value e.g. start with a-f and only 4 letters.

Comment: yes, I don't want values enumerated in XSD. They could be enumerated in java ( I was thinking about some config file readable by java, that would be easy to maintain).

Comment: okay, so read the config file, read the xml file and check if the values for the specific tags are contained by the config file.

Comment: and which parser would you recommend? considering the number of records in final XML and that I need to change english language of default error messages to different language. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

read [this JAXB Turorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) to see how to convert from and to xml